# What exactly we have to mention in osgi-extra.conf with respect to dotCMS

Tags: content-management-system, dotcms

I am new to dotCMS, can any one put light on below question,

I am working on the project called \osgi\com.dotcms.service, with respect to this project what entries we have to do in osgi-extra.conf file.

Comment: What is your question, exactly?

Answer (score 1):

Are you asking what you should put in this osgi-extra.conf file?

It's the place used to declare the set of packages that will be available to the OSGI plugins (i.e. jar files) you are going to deploy (AKA your plugins have something imported from other packages. You need to declare the packages in osgi-extra.conf file).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: @JBKing  Thanks for pointing this out. In this case, shall I delete this answer? Cuz I don't have enough reputation to put this under the comment of author's question yet.

Comment: @RaymondYin, in that case and looking over the question again, I'd likely leave it as I noticed more that there was the question starting your answer that would be better as a comment but the rest of your answer could be a reference. I wish the question was better worded as to the specific issue rather than a general request.